# Jenkins: Git plugin timeout when try to pull repositoty using SSH

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh

I trying to setup Jenkins to PULL repository from github using SSH. Here is what i have done so far

1> Installed Jenkins, GitHub and Git plugin on Windows 2012 r2 server and run the jenkins service under logged in user account. ( not local system account)

2>Created SSH as per the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) on GitHub. (Note i used passphrase while creating)

3>I can see private & public keys are created under

> c:\users{loggedusername}.ssh

3>Added SSH key to ssh-agent and also added public key to github

4>In jenkins, created new global credentials using SSH private Key and passphrase ( this is the passphrase i used while creating SSH)

5>In jenkins,configured github SSH url and used the SSH credentials created above

> git@github.com:mycompanyname/myrepo.git

6>Click on build now

7>In Console window i see the error below after 10 mins with statuscode -1

```
   Started by user James Smith
   Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\DEV\workspace
   Cloning the remote Git repository
   Cloning repository git@github.com:mycompanyname/myrepo.git
    > git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\DEV\workspace # timeout=10
   Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:mycompanyname/myrepo.git
    > git.exe --version # timeout=10
   using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH
    > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:mycompanyname/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:mycompanyname/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
   stdout: 
   stderr: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.XXX.XXX' to the list of known hosts.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1693)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1441)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:62)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:313)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:505)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1013)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1053)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
   ERROR: null
   Finished: FAILURE
```

I think i have setup SSH credential correct, otherwise on step 5 above i would have gotten red error from Jenkins if its not able to connect to GitHub

Also i can run the command below from gitbash and enter passphrase, and i was able to pull repository from gitbash.

```
git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:mycompanyname/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: I had a git repo that was so big that I needed to change the clone timeout. Check this [comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20445?focusedCommentId=195638&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-195638) for more info

Comment: if i use username/password & https url  then its working..however with SSH im getting above error. I think Its not able to connect using SSH but i dont know what i have missed

Answer (score 4):

Increase timeout for cloning and checkout

1. Go to job configuration and find git section
2. Add -> Advanced clone behaviours. There you can specify timeout and check 'shallow copy' (which is faster)
3. Add -> Advanced checkout behaviours. You can set time out for checkout.